# PHP apresenta erro "Failed to write session data" em momentos aleatorios

Tags: php, session, centos

Possuo um site que está totalmente funcional e o índice de falhas é de 0.0037%, entretanto todos o erros são os mesmos.

```
Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp)
```

Eu procurei por algumas informações em [PHP session handling error](http://shttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104065/php-session-handling-errors) e também em [Failed to write session data (files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022731/failed-to-write-session-data-files). *Porém ambas as soluções não solucionaram o problemas, além disso as perguntas aparentemente se referiam à um problema persistente, quero dizer um problema que era apresentado a todo o momento.*

No meu caso este problema ocorre durante curto espaço de tempo, durante em média dois minutos e não afeta todos os usuários, até porque são poucos dados nos logs. Nas últimas 24 horas isso ocorreu apenas entre as 17:52 até as 17:54, depois disso não houve nenhum erro do mesmo tipo e tudo continua funcionando normalmente. Por ser um espaço pequeno de tempo não consigo testar o site justamente nesse momento ou fazer outras verificações.

Queria saber o que pode está causando este problema.

Existe algum limite de arquivos por pasta ou alguma limitação na criação de novas sessões, que então bloqueie a escrita? Existe algum processo do PHP (ou até mesmo do próprio CentOS) que altere a permissão das pastas ou que possa está bloqueando a escrita?

*Eu ainda não tentei alterar a pasta onde é salvo as sessões, mas irei fazer isto em breve.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Descobri o problema, que era uma das coisas que suspeitava *mas achava que não era o problema.*

*Eu uso alguns softwares de teste de vulnerabilidades, embora eles não acusem erros eu comecei a achar que tais erros estavam relacionados à tais testes, porque os erros eram apresentados em "grande quantidade" após 2~3 horas dos testes serem iniciados, os testes são feitos em horários aleatórios!*

O problema que descobri é relacionado à uso de caracteres "inválidos" como valor do cookie da `SESSION`, isso causa o problema de leitura da `SESSION`.

### **Testando o problema:**

Se o cookie da sessão (por padrão tem nome de `PHPSESSID`) tiver com um valor do tipo `!@#$!%!@#$@#!!!#!#!@#%` ele será acusar o problema:

```
Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp)
```

Para alterar o valor do cookie você pode usar a extensão de [EditThisCookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg).

Se quiser, pode usar o Javascript para alterar o cookie:

```
var nome = "PHPSESSID";
var valor = "!$!@$!@@#!@#!@#";

document.cookie = nome+"="+valor;
```

### **Correção:**

Para causar o problema exige que algum curioso (sendo otimista) tenha alterado o valor do cookie usado para definir a sessão.

A correção que pensei foi a seguinte:

```
$sessao = "PHPSESSID";

if(isset($_COOKIE[$sessao]) && !preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9,-]+$/', $_COOKIE[$sessao])){
     unset($_COOKIE[$sessao]);
}

session_start();
```

**Isso seria uma solução genérica, não ideal.**

Primeiro é saber exatamente quais caracteres seriam válidos, isso depende somente disto:

```
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
```

Se for 4 irá ser de `[a-f0-9]`.
Se for 5 irá ser de `[a-v0-9]`.
Se for 6 irá ser de `[A-Za-z0-9,-]`.

> Leia a documentação em http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.sid-bits-per-character

Segundo é o número de caracteres válidos, o PHP por padrão gera sessões de 26 caracteres, isso depende da COMBINAÇÃO dos seguintes valores:

```
session.hash_function = md5
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
```

Essa combinação irá resultar na maior ou menor valor da sessão, logo precisará testar para alterar o número de caracteres do REGEX baseado no número de caracteres.

> Leia a resposta em https://stackoverflow.com/a/17032075/3043018

**No meu caso estou usando EXATAMENTE isto:**

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['_sid']) && !preg_match('/^[a-v0-9]{52}$/', $_COOKIE['_sid'])){
     unset($_COOKIE['_sid']);
}
```